# cProfile on a function that uses Argument Parser

Tags: python, cprofile

I am trying to run **cProfile** on a Python script that uses an **ArgumentParser** to parse arguments given from the Command Line. Amongst the arguments, there are two file names that are used by the script for data input.

I was wondering whether I am able to provide the arguments somehow via the **cProfile** in order to be able to profile my functions using actual data.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass them through on the command line like you normally would.

```
python -m cProfile -s time my_app.py <args>
```